# Python: May I vertically stack two pandas series to form a new series in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df_er with two columns, "aaa" and "aaa_rw". "aaa_rw" series is blank.

```
df_er['aaa']
Out[253]: 
Period
19930105    25.405
19930106    25.427
19930107    25.411
19930108    25.423
19930111    25.450

20200120    29.960
20200121    29.998
20200122    30.006
20200130    30.277
20200131    30.250
Name: aaa, Length: 6738, dtype: float64

df_er['aaa_rw']
Out[254]: 
Period
19930105     
19930106     
19930107     
19930108     
19930111     
           ..
20200120     
20200121     
20200122     
20200130     
20200131     
Name: aaa_rw, Length: 6738, dtype: object
```

I would like to create the series "aaa_rw" ("rw" means random walk) from "aaa" as follows: the first value is NaN, while the second value corresponds to "aaa"'s first value, the third value corresponds to "aaa"'s second value, etc. The idea is to vertically stack an NaN and part of the "aaa" series. I naively use np.vstack function but it does not work, as expected:

```
df_er['aaa_rw']= np.vstack((float("NaN"),df_er.iloc[0:len(df_er)-1,df_er.columns.get_loc('aaa')]))
```

Can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: it's not clear what is your expected output. Add your expected output too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The original series aaa is (X1, X2, X3, ...., XN). My expected output is (NaN, X1, X2, ......, X(N-1)).

Comment: Something like this will work `df.shift(periods=1)` You may want this check out: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html#pandas-series-shift)

```py
>>> df_er['aaa_rw'] = df_er.aaa.shift(1)
>>> df_er
             aaa  aaa_rw
Period
19930105  25.405     NaN
19930106  25.427  25.405
19930107  25.411  25.427
19930108  25.423  25.411
19930111  25.450  25.423
20200120  29.960  25.450
20200121  29.998  29.960
20200122  30.006  29.998
20200130  30.277  30.006
20200131  30.250  30.277
```